# Aligning text + button Terms of Use - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

but with the code below it's looking like this:

[image]

I had to change it to include open link in-app in safari. How can I align that?

```
HStack() {
    Text("By continuing, you agree to our ")
        .font(.system(size: 10))
    
    Button(action: {
        showTermsOfUse.toggle()
    }) {
        Text("Terms of Use (EULA)")
            .font(.system(size: 10))
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showTermsOfUse, content: {
            SFSafariViewWrapper(url: URL(string: "https://www....")!)
    })
    
    Text(" and acknowledge that you have read our")
        .font(.system(size: 10))
        .foregroundColor(.primary)
    
    Button(action: {
        showPrivacyPolicy.toggle()
    }) {
        Text("Privacy Policy.")
            .font(.system(size: 10))
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showPrivacyPolicy, content: {
            SFSafariViewWrapper(url: URL(string: "https://.....")!)
    })
}
```

This is how I had it before, which is the very first image above:

```
Text("By continuing, you agree to our [Terms of Service](https://www....) and acknowledge that you have read our [Privacy Policy](https:/...).")
```

Comment: What's wrong with your original markdown solution?

Comment: That way I can't open two links when clicked using in-app safari feature. It would open the safari app externally and I want to use the SFSafariViewWrapper. @George

Comment: @Arturo: The issue is here that once you pass the first line, the HStack itself would make issue! and for sure would be need just one  VStack with several HStack! instade one HStack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is how I solved it (and actually like the design better):

[image]

```
VStack {
    HStack {
        Text("By continuing, you agree to our ")
            .font(.system(size: 10))
        
        Button(action: {
            showTermsOfUse.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Terms of Use (EULA)")
                .font(.system(size: 10))
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showTermsOfUse, content: {
            SFSafariViewWrapper(url: URL(string: "https:...")!)
        })
    }
    
    HStack {
        Text(" and acknowledge that you have read our")
            .font(.system(size: 10))
        
        Button(action: {
            showPrivacyPolicy.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Privacy Policy.")
                .font(.system(size: 10))
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showPrivacyPolicy, content: {
            SFSafariViewWrapper(url: URL(string: "https:/...")!)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add `Spacer()` at the end in each `HStack` as well. Also edit `VStack` to `VStack(alignment: .leading)`

Comment: I actually like it in the center now. It aligns more with the design. Thanks @swiftPunk

Comment: that is also good in center

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be to use your private in-app registered URL schemas with predefined constants in path in original markdown, like

```
Text("By continuing, you agree to our [Terms of Service](yourapp://service_terms) and acknowledge that you have read our [Privacy Policy](yourapp://privacy_policy).")
```

which you can then handle and process as needed, say in `.onOpenURL`

Here is for reference (to avoid duplication) https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=onOpenURL

Comment: Would that open safari integrated into the app or externally?

Comment: It will give control back to your app and you can handle it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If You Would Like Here Is A Function Which Will Open A Link Once A Button Is Clicked

```
func openCustomURL(urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
    
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }
}
```

And Then

```
    Button(action: {
                    openCustomURL(urlString: "www.google.com")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Terms of Use (EULA)")
                                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                })
```